# how can I have dynamic location field in SOLR 5.X?

Tags: solr, geolocation, schema, geospatial

Tried the below:

```
<dynamicField name="Meta_p_*"    type="location"      indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="Meta_p_*_0_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="Meta_p_*_1_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Got Solr Excpetion

```
 Caused by: Dynamic field name 'Meta_p_*_0_coordinate' should have either a leading or a trailing asterisk, and no others.
```

tried:

```
 <dynamicField name="Meta_p_*"    type="location"      indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <Field name="Meta_p_*_0_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <Field name="Meta_p_*_1_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

got myself empty core but when tried to insert new document got:

```
 Error adding field 'Meta_p_mylocation'='45.17614,-93.87341' msg=LatLonType uses multiple fields.
```

The quastion - is there  a way to add dynamic field in Solr 5.X?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic field "Meta_p_*_0_coordinate" is type of double.

It will only store double values like 45.17614 ..

Solr gave an exception because you were trying to store kind of string ('45.17614,-93.87341') value.

I think solr doesn't support LatLon type field in dynamic field.

If you want to use spatial search feature of solr, you need to define field (non-dynamic) which is of type solr.LatLonType

See : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch